# Can't get accepted requests with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm developing an application for Android where user can send some challenge request to the other user and after that challenge request is accepted i'm updating status in that table for particular row and now i should be able to retrieve those accepted requests. I'm retrieving successfully pending challenge requests, but accepted challenge requests i can't retrieve. Actually i'm getting all rows from that table which is not good.

This is how my table `challenges` looks:

`id`

`user_one_id` reference to the table `users` with `user_id` from there

`user_two_id` reference to the table `users` with `user_id` from there

`status`

This is how i'm retrieving pending requests:

```
SELECT u.name, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, c.status, c.created_at, 
c.isRead, c.id FROM users u, challenges c 
WHERE c.user_two_id = ? AND c.status = 0 AND u.id = c.user_one_id 
ORDER BY c.created_at ASC
```

and this is how i tried to retrieve accepted requests, but not getting good results:

```
SELECT u.name, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, c.status, c.created_at, c.isRead, c.id FROM users u, challenges c 
WHERE c.user_one_id = ? AND 
    c.user_two_id = ? AND c.status = 1 AND u.id = c.user_one_id OR u.id = c.user_two_id 
ORDER BY c.created_at ASC
```

One note: It should be consider that sometimes the user that is going to be logged in could be the user with the id one or id two from table `challenges` because he could be maybe the one who is sending the request or someone who is receiving request.

**UPDATE**:

MySQL:

```
public function acceptedChallenges($user_one_id, $user_two_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.name, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, c.status, c.created_at, c.isRead, c.id FROM users u, challenges c 
                                WHERE c.user_one_id = ? AND 
                                        c.user_two_id = ? AND c.status = 1 AND (u.id = c.user_one_id OR u.id = c.user_two_id)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_one_id, $user_two_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $request = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $request;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Below i'm calling function:

```
$app->post('/accepted_challenges', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {

verifyRequiredParams(array('user_one_id', 'user_two_id'));

$response = array();
$db = new DbHandler();

$user_one_id = $app->request->post('user_one_id');
$user_two_id = $app->request->post('user_two_id');

$requests = $db->acceptedChallenges($user_one_id, $user_two_id);

if ($requests != NULL) {

    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["requests"] = array();

    while ($request = $requests->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["name"] = $request["name"];
        $tmp["id"] = $request["id"];
        $tmp["user_one_id"] = $request["user_one_id"];
        $tmp["user_two_id"] = $request["user_two_id"];
        $tmp["created_at"] = $request["created_at"];
        $tmp["isRead"] = $request["isRead"];

        array_push($response["requests"], $tmp);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "No pending requests.";
}

echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

Comment: Nobody's going to be able to do much without some sample data and an expected output. Try setting something up at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: u.id = c.user_one_id OR u.id = c.user_two_id  should be wrapped I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the result the way you need

```
SELECT u.name, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, c.status, c.created_at, c.isRead, c.id FROM users u, challenges c 
WHERE c.user_one_id = ? AND 
    c.user_two_id = ? AND c.status = 1 AND (u.id = c.user_one_id OR u.id = c.user_two_id )
ORDER BY c.created_at ASC
```

UPDATES

```
SELECT u.name, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, c.status, c.isRead, c.id FROM users u, challenges c 
WHERE u.id = ? AND c.status = 1 AND (c.user_one_id=? OR c.user_two_id=? )

? must be the id you are posting
```

Comment: I'm not getting any response now in json.

Comment: Are you sure you are binding correct params to the query?

Comment: Yes, and when i wrapped those ids i'm not getting any response in json, but without wrapping it i'm getting as i said all records from table.

Comment: I don't why i'm getting empty json. I will update my code with PHP

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4110/1 look at my sqlfiddle and i forgot, the post parameters i need to pass are the user id which is logged in. So for the user_id_one and user_id_two i should pass the same id. If the user with the id 2 is logged in i will pass that id for the both id because he should retrieve only his accepted requests so i need to check on which place he is.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic I updated your fiddle and it does return one row which it should. You might need to change it so it u.id=1 should be the id from post parameter and you will get correct result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110006/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-sameer-jain).